# connection string for classic asp application using odbc 11 for sql server

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, connection-string, dsn

We have a classic asp application, we lost connection with the database.  In application server we are able to connect to database only through odbc driver 11 for sql server. Have tried other native client drivers to establish connection which remained unsuccessful. The only supported driver is odbc 11 for sql server.

Have tried following connection strings -

ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server:

```
{"Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server };  Data Source =servername; Initial Catalog= dbname; Uid=username ; Pwd=password; "}
```

DSN:

```
{" DSN=dsnname;Uid=username ; Pwd=password; Database=dbname"}
```

Still unable to establish connection.

Can you please suggest the connection strings for odbc driver 11 for sql server?

Comment: Is this for a new server install?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @erg  i have this error.. "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" .Using ODBC driver 11 we are able to connect to database with both 32 & 64 bit DSN.We are unable to connect through connection string.

Comment: @Vanquished Wombat  Till now we used OLEDB provider for connection string. After TLS1. 2 update,  we are getting handshake error so we tried system DSN and able to establish connection only through ODBC driver11

Answer (score 0):

The is an MS fix for these symtoms here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/tls-1-2-support-for-sql-server-2008-2008-r2-2012-and-2014/

Issue described as below. The list of items fixed includes SQL Native client and ODBC client.

> SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), Report Server, and Report Manager don’t connect to the database engine after you apply the fix for SQL Server 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, or 2014. Report Server and Report Manager fail and return the following error message:
>
> The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable)
>
> This issue occurs because SSMS, Report Manager, and Reporting Services Configuration Manager use ADO.NET, and ADO.NET support for TLS 1.2 is available only in the .NET Framework 4.6. For earlier versions of the .NET Framework, you have to apply a Windows update so that ADO.NET can support TLS 1.2 communications for the client. The Windows updates that enable TLS 1.2 support in earlier versions of .NET framework are listed in the table in the “How to know whether you need this update” section of KB3135244.

Found as to[ Google hit searching for [https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=oledb+tls1.2](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=oledb%20tls1.2) - there are many more interesting-looking hits in the top ten there that should get you going.

Please come back and self-answer if this solves your issue and there were any other peculiar or unexpected mods you had to make.